# Using database binary search in java

Tags: java

I have a project in java that search a data from a database. already do this but applying the binary search algorithm is very hard to understand.

How to apply binary search in java using a database? 
How do i put my data into an array?
Can someone hep me for my project.

Comment: I can help you if you post some code of what you try so far.

Comment: @JohnReyLoquiasNierra This is not a code factory. Try it out on your own and come back and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I have a table then it has five column, ID is a primary key of my table. my problem is this how can i convert it into array in java?

Comment: can you give some idea on how to start with it sir?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a database has searching and indexing built in.  If you are using an SQL or NoSQL database, you need to look at the instructions for that product on how to do a search.

If you want to use a binary search in Java;

- sort your collection with Arrays.sort or Collections.sort
- Use Arrays.binarySearch or Collections.binarySearch

Comment: I have a table then it has five column, ID is a primary key of my table. my problem is this how can i convert it into array in java? can you give some idea on how to start with it sir?

Comment: @johnrey you need to use a class with five fields, one of which is the ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you search a record in database using some identifier (like id, name, some date). In order to have a binary search capability the column that hold such field (the field you would like to use in search) should have index in DB. To have an index on a column in DB the colum should be either denoted as "key" or you can create index manually, index is not a free, so not all columns have index by default - index take additional space and time on INSERT, but it pays off when you need to search DB for something using that field. Knowing those trade-offs the deasigner of DB should choose which columns (or group of columns in "clustered index") in which tables have or not indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in database  we search a record  using some identifiers(like name ,GPA etc).As in binary search we first found the mid point after finding this we easily  found the field that is required to us because mid point value helps us to understand that we have to move left side of the array or the right side of the array. Our field( the field we like to use  for searching) are consider as a column in database so the coulmn is consider as a key in database.if you want to use binary search in java then use Arrays. binary search , Array sort